# Weight sum inside Scrollview - Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-layout-weight

I am creating a class schedule in my activity, is composed of several columns and rows. In some cases there are only a few rows and left a blank space at the bottom of the screen (CASE 1). In others there are too many rows and need to use the scroll (CASE 3).

What I do is that when the rows are few and do not fill the screen, the size of each one are equal and fill all the space... (CASE 2)

Here a picture for better understanding:

[image]

**Case 1:**

```
 ScrollView:

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    adroid:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:fillViewport="true"

  LinearLayout:

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    adroid:layout_height="fill_parent"

  Button:

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="43dp"
```

**Case 2:**

```
ScrollView:

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    adroid:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:fillViewport="true"

  LinearLayout:

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    adroid:layout_height="fill_parent"

  Button:

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="0dp" 

    android:layout_weight="1"
```

If I add rows directly in the xml everything works fine, but when I add them programmatically does not work.

Comment: if its just kind of listing instead of ScrollView you can try with ListView which a best way to show listing.

Comment: show code when you are dynamically adding rows

Comment: Can you post case 3 ?